# What is the difference between using "over" and "against" with the word "outrage"?

Tags: meaning

Examples:

> 1 - An outrage against the ruling.
>
> 2 - An outrage over the ruling.

It seems that they are almost the same thing to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are at least two distinct uses of *[outrage](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/learner-english/outrage_1)*.

When *outrage* refers to an insult or attack, *against* refers to its subject and *over* is not used:

> - The art exhibit is an *outrage against* public decency.
> - The CIA's methods are an *outrage against* the Constitution.
> - The *Twilight* series is an *outrage against* literature.

When *outrage* refers to the reaction to such an insult or attack (anger, horror, moral indignation, etc.), *over* or *at* refers to the cause whereas *against* refers to the target:

> - The workers voiced *outrage at* the new leave policy.
> - The lackluster pitching has stirred *outrage against* the coaching staff.
> - The protesters' *outrage against* bankers *over* recently announced performance bonuses reached a fever pitch after the *Times* article.

Comment: hmm, so using "at" or "over" is virtually the same thing?

Comment: @DragonBuster -- *at* might suggest more specificity.  You are outraged over the crime rate, but outraged at some particular crime.  But yes, virtually the same thing.